# What is the best arrangement of gem dragons in their habitats?

Tags: dragonvale

Currently, there are 4 habitats on the Gem Dragon island, and each can hold multiple gem dragons. I finally have more than 4 gem dragons, so now I have to decide how to arrange them. What is the best arrangement to earn max gems?  I'm particularly interested in avoiding gem loss by leaving them for too long. They have such a long timer I often forget to check them in a timely manner.

Comment: Not sure what you mean...what's the concern? They all raise gems at the same rate don't they? Just don't forget to check the game for more than 1  * (3/dragons in habitat) weeks and you should be good regardless of arrangement

Comment: The right answer may be "it doesn't matter how you arrange them," but that's why I'm asking. With one in each, they seem to all be on different timers. I assume the timers are dragon based - not habitat based, so doesn't that create synchronization penalties once you start to mix them?  Maybe after the first synchronization it no longer matters though. I'll try to explain better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the Gem dragons thus far (except the Jade dragon, which has as slightly slower timer) have the exact same timer and all the habitats have the exact same storage capacity. The only optimal pattern is to make sure as few dragons are in each habitat as possible; instead of keeping 3 in one and 1 in all others, put 2 in each habitat, for example. If you have Jade dragons, space them out evenly (or, more likely, keep a single one) to minimize their impact on your gem earning rate.

At level 10 each dragon will give one gem every week (always level these dragons to 10 first! they have by far the most to gain from your food). Each habitat will hold three gems.

Comment: For information, I tested moving dragons into the same habitat, and the timer follows the dragon. I don't know what happens if that habitat is full though. Even if there is no way to reset the timer, you can wait to hatch until the opportune day - to use the twice/week strategy. I suspect the hibernation cave will reset the timer, but I don't want to interrupt any of mine at the moment.

Comment: Hmm... But as I look at it, isn't the dragon cap per habitat 3?

Comment: @EBongo oh, yeah, I had that backwards (was thinking 3 habitats of 4) so yeah I don't think changing timers is necessary at all

Comment: You may want to update your answer, as the new Jade Dragon, which is also a Gem dragon, does not have the same earning rate as the dragons previously released (only 2/month at max level). The core of your answer would remain the same, but it's no longer accurate that they're all equal.

Answer (score 1):

My friends discovered that putting three dragons in one habitat makes one gem per day (increasing gem production).

Answer (score 1):

I found that the gemstone timer is not on the dragons themselves, but on the habitat.  I had 1to dragon in two seperate habitats (turquoise and peridot) for two hours after collecting my weekly gems, and when moved into the other two habitats on gemstone island, the timers reset to 7the days. But when put back into either of the two original habitats, the timer loses the 2 hours. Also, 2 gemstone dragons in a new 7 day time habitat (ie: the habitats that have never held a gemstone dragon yet) make it 4 days to collect, but im not sure if i get 2 gems in 4 daus or just one. Ill let you know .....in 4 days lol.

Comment: Hi @Bernardo, welcome to Arqade!  Recently, I have observed the same behavior as you - I believe that Backflip changed it from the original behavior.  Can you confirm if it is possible to "hop" a dragon from between habitats to get more than 1 gem per week from the same dragon?  I now have well more than 12 gemstones, so there it isn't that useful for me to know - but I'm sure others would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

I checked and only received 1gem from two in the same habitat. The timer doesn't follow the dragons,I have 4 now (opal, peridot, turquoise, emerald) and one habitat has a 3 day timer with one dragon in it, a 30 hr timer with 2, and a 25 hour timer with three. so I'm keeping two per habitat, it makes the most significant upgrade per dragon (4 days not 7) whereas a normal 7 day timer with 3 dragons makes it 3 days and some change. What you can do is get your gem early by switching from 2 to 3 dragons when there are only hours left on the timer. then once the gem is collected move back to having 2per habitat. So you can't receive one gem per dragon but you can get one gem per habitat and with 2 dragons in all four habitats you can get 4 gems in 4 days and depending on when you place the dragons in the habitats, you can set it up where your getting 1 gem per day.

Comment: Hi @Bernardo.  Thanks for following up.  Ideally instead of adding a new answer, you would edit your previous answer with the new content.  A one or two sentence summary is also always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't make any difference in terms of gems. But for purely aesthetic purposes, I put aquamarine and pearl dragons in habitats where they have lagoons, because they are the only two gemstone dragons who can swim. Personally I keep pearl at the top habitat and aquamarine at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I put the dragons depending on their month. January-March goes together than April-june, July- sep and finally Oct- December